# Am I using the iOS "detail disclosure" and "disclosure" correctly?

Tags: ios, tableview, disclosure

Am I using the "detail disclosure" and "disclosure" accessories correctly in this screenshot?

The "Description" and "Business Impact" rows navigate to a single text view with only multi-page text displayed expanding on the truncated summary shown in the row. The "Closures" and "Status Updates" navigate to table views.

[image: iOS Disclosures]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are three options you're discussing: Disclosure Indicator, Detail Disclosure Button, and Detail Button.

The chevron only (`UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator`) indicates you should be able to tap on the row to navigate to a new view (commonly called a "detail view").

The two button options (`UITableViewCellAccessoryDetailDisclosureButton` and `UITableViewCellAccessoryDetailButton`):

- Detail button will show a blue "i" button only.
- Detail disclosure button will *also* show the chevron.

The button indicates a **different** action from tapping on the row, handled in `tableView:accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath:`.

If tapping the blue "i" does the same thing as tapping the row, you are not doing it correctly.

Comment: Thank you. How should just the detail accessory be used?

Answer (score 0):

The disclosure indicator (>) is used to indicate that tapping the cell triggers an action, so drilling down and displaying a detail view are both fine for this.

The detail disclosure should indicate that something different happens if you tap that button than if you tapped the cell, so if you are not doing anything different with the i, you should remove it and leave just the disclosure indicator.